# Devise, no E-Mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I installed devise.

I run rails server -e development and set this line in config/environments:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'localhost:3000'}
```

Devises says:

```
 message with a confirmation link has been sent to your email address. Please open the      link to activate your account.
```

But I didn't receive any mail.

What do you think?

Comment: Did you setup the smtp configuration in `development.rb`?

Comment: no how to do this? Ah I have another line added: config.mailer_sender = "myapp@mail.de" in devise.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these lines to your `development.rb` file

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'baci.lindsaar.net',
  :user_name            => '<username>',
  :password             => '<password>',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

More info about sending and setting up email [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Comment: thanks a lot. Is it possible to set an login by default without registration for a root user?

Comment: You can manually create a user `u=User.create(:email => "abc@xyz.com", :password => "123456", :password_confirmation => "123456")` then `u.confirm!` to complete registration without clicking on link