# NoMethodError for Email in Actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Im a NoMethodError for my purchase confirmation. Not sure what I am missing here.
    NoMethodError at /purchases
    undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

```
purchase_confirmationapp/mailers/purchase_mailer.rb

     #   en.purchase_mailer.purchase_confirmation.subject
8   #
9   def purchase_confirmation(purchase)
10     @greeting = "Hi"
11     
12     mail to: purchase.email, subject: "Purchase Confirmation"
13   end
14 end


createapp/controllers/purchases_controller.rb

1 class PurchasesController < InheritedResources::Base
2 before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
3         def create
4                 @purchase = Purchase.new(params[:purchase])
5   if @purchase.save
6           PurchaseMailer.purchase_confirmation(@purchase).deliver
7   redirect_to "/thankyou"
8 else
9 
10   render :action => "new"
11 end
```

Any advice?

After editing and removing @ symbol, changing @purchase to purchase I now receive this error

```
    _app_views_purchase_mailer_purchase_confirmation_text_erb

1 <%= @email.purchase %>
2 
3 <%= @greeting %>, thanks for your purchase! We're on it! 

    purchase_confirmationapp/mailers/purchase_mailer.rb

7   #   en.purchase_mailer.purchase_confirmation.subject
8   #
9   def purchase_confirmation(purchase)
 10     @greeting = "Hi"
 11     
 12     mail to: purchase.email, subject: "Purchase Confirmation"
 13   end
 14 end

    createapp/controllers/purchases_controller.rb
1 class PurchasesController < InheritedResources::Base
2 before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
3         def create
4                 @purchase = Purchase.new(params[:purchase])
5   if @purchase.save
6           PurchaseMailer.purchase_confirmation(@purchase).deliver
7   redirect_to "/thankyou"
8 else
9 
 10   render :action => "new"
 11 end

    Rendered purchase_mailer/purchase_confirmation.text.erb (2.1ms)
```

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 176ms

```
>>NoMethodError - undefined method `purchase' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/purchase_mailer/purchase_confirmation.text.erb:1:in `_app_views_purchase_mailer_purchase_confirmation_text_erb___3663910894988497772_70151297381080'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  (gem) actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:701:in `block in collect_responses_and_parts_order'
  (gem) actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:712:in `each'
  (gem) actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:712:in `each_template'
  (gem) actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:697:in `collect_responses_and_parts_order'
  (gem) actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:636:in `mail'
  app/mailers/purchase_mailer.rb:12:in `purchase_confirmation'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  (gem) actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:457:in `process'
  (gem) actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:452:in `initialize'
  (gem) actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:439:in `new'
  (gem) actionmailer-3.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:439:in `method_missing'
  app/controllers/purchases_controller.rb:6:in `create'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__3758076575822448262__process_action__1783438763289863484__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  (gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  (gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  (gem) journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.3.2/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:51:in `app_call'
  (gem) better_errors-0.3.2/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:45:in `call'
  (gem) warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  (gem) warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  (gem) warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  (gem) rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  (gem) activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1428976172628906859__call__3073148256851134214__callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  (gem) railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  (gem) actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  (gem) railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  (gem) rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/russell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/russell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/russell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Line 12 - remove the @ sign before the variable:
`mail to: purchase.email, subject: "Purchase Confirmation"`

Comment: Now I receive a undefined method 'purchase' for nil:Nilclass @Andrei

Comment: Could you please provide a full error trace?

Comment: @Andrei I added the full trace at the bottom of the original post

Comment: You just reposted the purchase_mailer and the purchases_controller again. Was there anything else in the error trace?

Comment: @Andrei I pasted what my terminal is reading. Thats a snippet of it anyways.

Comment: Have you even tried my edited solution?

Comment: @benchwarmer - i did try your solution and it and i no longer have the  errors. going to check my mail. thanks. ill let you know. I didn't down vote your prior post btw. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `instance variable` before you can use those in views. In your case its `purchase` variable. So make mailer method look like this

```
 def purchase_confirmation(purchase)
    @greeting = "Hi"
    @purchase = purchase
    mail to: purchase.email, subject: "Purchase Confirmation"
  end
end
```

In the view you should do this

```
<%= @purchase.email %>

<%= @greeting %>, thanks for your purchase! We're on it!
```

Comment: Alright @benchwarmer - really close. No errors and my terminal says (3.1ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered purchase_mailer/purchase_confirmation.text.erb (0.6ms)

Sent mail to  (136ms)
Date: Wed, 27 Feb 2013 13:02:23 -0500
From: orders@itcinema.com
Message-ID: <512e4a2fc1233_be503fcd5f070eb035858@Russells-MacBook-Pro.local.mail>
Subject: Purchase Confirmation
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit



Hi, thanks for your purchase! We're on it!

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/thankyou
Completed 302 Found in 308ms (ActiveRecord: 4.5ms)

Comment: Checkout this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14942498/1087546

And be sure to restart the server after following all the steps

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to make your instance variable accessible to other classes:

```
 class PurchasesController < InheritedResources::Base
 #adding this will allow you to access the instance variable in other classes. 
 attr_accessor :purchase
2 before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
3         def create
4                 @purchase = Purchase.new(params[:purchase])
5   if @purchase.save
6           PurchaseMailer.purchase_confirmation(@purchase).deliver
7   redirect_to "/thankyou"
8 else
9 
10   render :action => "new"
11 end
```